# Infer a generic type based on another specified generic type and use it

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, covariance

First of all, I want to point out, that I already have a working solution, but I am trying to see if there is a way to make the code cleaner and less cumbersome.

Here is my situation. I have actually simplified the situation and created a fake example to make the illustration clear. I am just going to lay out a concrete example showing what I have already done, and it works.

Suppose we have these classes:

```
public abstract class Shape{ //...elided... }
public class Square : Shape { //...elided... }
public class Circle : Shape { //...elided... }
```

And suppose there's some kind of class that does something with them like this:

```
public class ShapeThingy
{
     public static void MakeSquaresDance(List<Squares> squares){ //...elided... }
     public static void RollCircles(List<Circles> circles){ //...elided... }
}
```

Now suppose I want to test the ShapeThingy class. Suppose that for some of the tests, I want to substitute MockSquares and MockCircles into the lists in place of Squares and Circles. Also, suppose that setting up the MockCircles and the MockSquares is very similar, such that I want to have one method to create the lists of mock shapes, and I tell this method the type of shape that I need. Here is how I have implemented it:

```
public class Tests
{
      [Test]
      public void TestDancingSquares()
      {
          List<Squares> mockSquares = GetMockShapes<Square, MockSquare>();
          ShapeThingy.MakeSquaresDance(mockSquares);

          Assert.Something();
      }

      [Test]
      public void TestRollingCircles()
      {
          List<Circles> mockCircles = GetMockShapes<Circle, MockCircle>();
          ShapeThingy.RollCircles(mockCircles );

          Assert.Something();
      }


      private List<TBase> GetMockShapes<TBase, TMock>()
         where TBase : Shape
         where TMock : TBase, new()
      {
         List<TBase> mockShapes = new List<TBase>();

         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         {
            mockShapes.Add(MockShapeFactory.CreateMockShape<TMock>());
         }
      }

}

public class MockSquare : Square { //...elided... }
public class MockCircle : Circle { //...elided... }

public class MockShapeFactory
{
    public static T CreateMockShape<T>()
        where T : Shape, new()
    {
        T mockShape = new T();
        //do some kind of set up
        return mockShape;
    }
}
```

Now this works fine. The problem I have with it is that you have specify to GetMockShapes() both the desired output type of the list, and the mock type that you actually want the list to contain. When in reality, I already know that if I ask GetMockShapes() for List<Square>, then it should actually be filled with MockSquare. It's kind of cumbersome to have to specify both things over and over.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
      private List<TBase> GetMockShapes<TBase>()
         where TBase : Shape
      {
         List<TBase> mockShapes = new List<TBase>();

         Type mockType = getAppropriateMockType<TBase>();

         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         {
            //compiler error: typeof(mockType) doesn't work here
            mockShapes.Add(MockShapeFactory.CreateMockShape<typeof(mockType)>());
         }
      }

      private Type getAppropriateMockType<TBase>()
      {
         if(typeof(TBase).Equals(typeof(Square)))
         {
            return typeof(MockSquare);
         }

         if(typeof(TBase).Equals(typeof(Circle)))
         {
            return typeof(MockCircle);
         }

         //else
         throw new ArgumentException(typeof(TBase).ToString() + " cannot be converted to a mock shape type.");
      }

      //add then a test would look like this
      //(one less word, one less chance to screw up)
      [Test]
      public void TestDancingSquares()
      {
          List<Squares> mockSquares = GetMockShapes<Square>();
          ShapeThingy.MakeSquaresDance(mockSquares);

          Assert.Something();
      }
```

The problem is that version won't compile, and I can't figure out a way around it. Maybe what I want to do is not possible.

Now at this point you may be thinking, "If he just uses IEnumerable<T> instead of List<T>, then he can take advantage of covariance in C# 4.0 and he won't have to do any of this crap," which is true, but but in our real code, we are not using List<T>, but rather a custom concrete type, Something<T> (and it is not an IEnumerable-style collection), and I don't have the ability to change the usage of Something<T> and introduce a covariant interface ISomething<out T> right now.

Anyways, all I am trying to do, I guess, is trying to save myself from having to type one extra word whenever I call GetMockShapes(), so it's not really that big of a deal, and I dunno, maybe it's good that both types are specified so that it's plain to see. I just thought it would be cool if I could figure out some way to do this, and I would learn something new as well. I mostly want to know if this can be done to satisfy my curiosity. I don't think it's really that important in terms of code quality.

Comment: well, in your example it won't compile because `getAppropriateMockType` is not specified as generic.  Specify it as generic with the same constraints as the first method and it'll work?

Comment: Ah, thank you. That fixes one of the two compiler errors, but there's still another. I corrected that code, and I also added a comment to show the part that is still causes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem now is that you can't invoke a generic with a `Type` instance, you need a compile-time type handle for that.

To get around this you can:

- Modify the `MockShapeFactory.CreateMockShape<T>` method to take a `Type` instance rather than write it as generic - but the actual creation of the instance would probably be harder then.
- Dynamically bind to the 'correct' version of the CreateMockShape method (based on the type returned from `getAppropriateMockType`) using reflection.

For the second - this test code might prove helpful:

```
#region some stubs (replaced with your types)

public class Shape { }
public class MockSquare : Shape { }
public class MockCircle : Shape { }

public class MockShapeFactory
{
  //I've added a constraint so I can new the instance
  public static T CreateMockShape<T>()
    where T : Shape, new()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Creating instance of {0}", typeof(T).FullName);
    return new T();
  }
}

#endregion

//you can cache the reflected generic method
System.Reflection.MethodInfo CreateMethodBase =
  typeof(MockShapeFactory).GetMethod(
    "CreateMockShape", 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public 
    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static
  );

[TestMethod]
public void TestDynamicGenericBind()
{
  //the DynamicBindAndInvoke method becomes your replacement for the 
  //MockShapeFactory.CreateMockShape<typeof(mockType)>() call
  //And you would pass the 'mockType' parameter that you get from
  //getAppropriateMockType<TBase>();
  Assert.IsInstanceOfType
    (DynamicBindAndInvoke(typeof(MockCircle)), typeof(MockCircle));

  Assert.IsInstanceOfType
    (DynamicBindAndInvoke(typeof(MockSquare)), typeof(MockSquare));
}
//can change the base type here according to your generic
//but you will need to do a cast e.g. <
public Shape DynamicBindAndInvoke(Type runtimeType)
{
  //make a version of the generic, strongly typed for runtimeType
  var toInvoke = CreateMethodBase.MakeGenericMethod(runtimeType);
  //should actually throw an exception here.
  return (Shape)toInvoke.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

It looks worse than it is - the goal is to replace the call to the factory's generic method with one that accepts a `Type` instance - which is what `DynamicBindAndInvoke(Type)` does in this example.  It might look pointless in this test - but that's only because I'm feeding in types known at compile time - in your case the type being passed would be the one retrieved from your `getAppropriateMockType` method.

Note that I've assumed that your factory method is a static on `MockShapeFactory` here. If it's not, then the reflection and invoke code would have to change to search for an instance method and to pass the instance of the factory as the first parameter to `Invoke`.

This pattern can be extended to compile delegates, thus speeding it all up, but for a test environment that kind of optimisiation is probably pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's a very good way to do things, but I got the `GetMockShapes` method working the way you were looking for. The idea is to start with the `MockShapeFactory`, get its `CreateMockShape` method, convert it to the appropriate generic version and invoke it to create an object of the correct type.

That gets an `object` though, and `mockShapes`'s `Add` method only accepts the correctly typed `Shape`. I couldn't figure out how to dynamically cast the new `mockShape` to its appropriate type. That would have avoided the need to invoke the builder through reflection anyway, I think.

I circumvented the type checking system instead (like I said, "not sure it's a very good way to do things"). I started with the `mockShapes` list, got its runtime type, got its `Add` method, and invoked that with the newly created object. The compiler expects objects for the method and allows this; reflection enforces proper typing at runtime. Bad things might happen if `GetAppropriateMockType` ever returns an inappropriate type.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System;

private List<TBase> GetMockShapes<TBase>()
     where TBase : Shape
{
    Type TMock = getAppropriateMockType<TBase>();

    // Sanity check -- if this fails, bad things might happen.
    Assert(typeof(TBase).IsAssignableFrom(TMock));

    List<TBase> mockShapes = new List<TBase>();

    // Find MockShapeFactory.CreateMockShape() method
    MethodInfo shapeCreator = typeof(MockShapeFactory).GetMethod("CreateMockShape");

    // Convert to CreateMockShape<TMock>() method
    shapeCreator = shapeCreator.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { TMock });

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        // Invoke the method to get a generic object
        // The object to invoke on is null because the method is static
        // The parameter array is null because the method expects no parameters
        object mockShape = shapeCreator.Invoke(null, null);

        mockShapes.GetType()                 // Get the type of mockShapes
            .GetMethod("Add")                // Get its Add method
            .Invoke(                         // Invoke the method
                mockShapes,                  // on mockShapes list
                new object[] { mockShape }); // with mockShape as argument.
    }

    return mockShapes;
}
```

## A better (but situation-specific) way

After some more thinking I realized there's an unstated assumption here you can abuse. You're trying to make a `List<TBase>` and fill it with `TMock`. The whole point of `TMock` is to impersonate `TBase`, so `TMock` *is a* `TBase`. In fact, the `List` even uses `TBase` as its type parameter.

That's important because it means you don't have to cast the generic object to a `TMock`, you can just cast it to a `TBase`. Since `TBase` is known at compile time, you can use a simple static cast instead of circumventing the typing system to pass a generic object to a typed method. I think this way is a lot better if you can use it.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System;

private List<TBase> GetMockShapes<TBase>()
     where TBase : Shape
{
    Type TMock = getAppropriateMockType<TBase>();

    // Sanity check -- if this fails, bad things might happen.
    Assert(typeof(TBase).IsAssignableFrom(TMock));

    List<TBase> mockShapes = new List<TBase>();

    // Find MockShapeFactory.CreateMockShape() method
    MethodInfo shapeCreator = typeof(MockShapeFactory).GetMethod("CreateMockShape");

    // Convert to CreateMockShape<mockType>() method
    shapeCreator = shapeCreator.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { TMock });

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        // Invoke the method to get a generic object
        // The object to invoke on is null because the method is static
        // The parameter array is null because the method expects no parameters
        object mockShape = shapeCreator.Invoke(null, null);

        //
        // Changes start here
        //

        // Static cast the mock shape to the type it's impersonating
        TBase mockBase = (TBase)mockShape;

        // Now this works because typeof(mockBase) is known at compile time.
        mockShapes.Add(mockBase);
    }

    return mockShapes;
}
```